# How to convert binary text to a string?

Tags: c#

How to convert binary text to a string using C#?

I've tried this way, but, I'm getting as output binaries converted onto string:

```
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (byte b in fileBytes)
{
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
}
string str = sb.ToString();
```

Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the encoding is UTF8:

```
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes);
```

Comment: How to read and save into a string the content of one text file with preservation of the newLine and special characters?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend what encoding the source file uses, but you want `Encoding.GetString()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If the source file is UTF8 encoded, you could do something like

```
var output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes);
```

Comment: How to read and save into a string the content of one text file with preservation of the newLine and special characters?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(fileBytes);
```

Comment: How to read and save into a string the content of one text file with preservation of the newLine and special characters?